# Strange behaviour when using ServerSide or bServerSide DataTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have the following code I am working on:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshMaintTable = $('#maint-table').dataTable( {
            "sAjaxSource": 'pcheck/ajax/maint_json.txt',
            "ServerSide": true,
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mData": "maint_owner" },
                { "mData": "maint_desc" },
            ],
        } );
        setInterval (function() {
            refreshMaintTable.fnDraw();
        }, 500);
    } );
</script>
```

JSON Data:

```
{
  "draw": 1,
  "recordsTotal": 20,
  "recordsFiltered": 20,
  "data": [
    {
      "maint_owner": "cparrot",
      "maint_desc": "Trip to Dubai"
    },
    {
      "maint_owner": "mbean",
      "maint_desc": "Upgrade to iPhone"
    }
  ]
}
```

Scenario 1:

with the above like that,

```
the result count shows **Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries** which is correct
the refreshMaintTable does not refresh the data table
```

Scenario 2:

when i change from **ServerSide: true** to **bServerSide: true**

```
the refreshMaintTable starts refreshing the data table
the result count then shows **Showing 1 to 2 of 20 entries** which is not correct since I only have 2 entries
```

Is there anything I am missing here between using server side processing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the plugin itself. There are many discrepancies in the documentation. It's very fragmented. Datatables is very much trial and error.

Comment: you might be right. I have tried different combination but no luck

Comment: From using datatables a lot personally, all I can say is use what works. Don't fight it, just hack it.

Comment: Best advise in a decade. I will remove that count and write a simple jquery to count the total and display result elsewhere